# Counting elements in a list with given property values

Tags: python

I'm using Python 2.7. I have a list of objects that each include a property called vote that can have values of either yes or no, and I want to count the number of yes and no votes. One way to do this is:

```
list = [ {vote:'yes'}, {vote:'no'}, {vote:'yes'} ] #...
numYesVotes = len([x for x in list if x.vote=='yes'])
numNoVotes = len([x for x in list if x.vote=='no'])
```

but it seems horribly wasteful/inefficient to me to build these lists only to get their lengths and

First question: Am I right about that? Wouldn't it a good bit more efficient to simply loop through the list once and increment counter variables? i.e:

```
numYesVotes = numNoVotes = 0;
for x in list: 
    if x.vote == 'yes': 
        numYesVotes++
    else:
        numNoVotes++
```

or is there something about list comprehensions that would make them more efficient here?

Second question: I'm just learning to use lambdas, and I have a feeling this is a perfect use case for one - but I can't quite figure out how to use one here how might I do that?

Comment: you should avoid naming your variable `list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it is faster to do:

```
sum(1 for x in L if x.vote=='yes')
```

Than:

```
 len([x for x in L if x.vote=='yes'])
```

As no list has to be created.

Answer (score 4):

See [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
Counter(x.vote for x in mylst)
```

**Edit:**

Example:

```
yn = Counter("yes" if x%2 else "no" for x in range(10))
print(yn["yes"],yn["no"])
```

Comment: You should also include how to get the count from this

Answer (score 0):

The `lambda` form;

```
t =lambda lst: len([ v for x in lst for k,v in x.items() if v=='yes'])
#print (t(mylst))
```

`mylst` is the list that you want to check how much yes or no in that. Use key-dict methods.

Demo;

```
mylst = [ {"vote":'yes'}, {"vote":'no'}, {"vote":'yes'} ]
t =lambda lst: len([ v for x in lst for k,v in x.items() if v=='yes'])
print (t(mylst))

>>> 
2
>>>
```